# webview is not taking full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

[image]

i have simple layout with two buttons as you can see in the image , when i click on google button it opens google website in the webview as you see it is not opening google website on full screen it is showing those buttons two ,but when i remove scrollbar from my main layout, then webview shows google website on the full screen, how can i fix this problem because i want to user scrollview in my main layout.. here is my main.xml

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_click_login"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Google"/>

    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_gmail"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Gmail"/>

  <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
 </WebView>

</LinearLayout>      
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Make use of 2 activity, One with buttons and one more with webview, When u click on button it will go to another activity with webview.

Comment: what you want ..button should disappeared when web view get open ?

Comment: Do not put a `WebView` in a `ScrollView` -- that will not work well.

Answer (score 0):

> when i click on google button it opens google website in the webview
>   as you see it is not opening google website on full screen

This is because probably you are using same `Activity` with same `XML` layout, where are another `widgets`. But solution is not difficult.

**1.** First create something like web.xml with one widget `WebView`.
**2.** Then create another class extending from Activity called for example `WebBrowser.java`
**3.** Add it to your `Manifest.xml` as `<activity android:name=".WebBrowser"></activity>`
**4.** In your WebBrowser class will set your layout with `setContentView(R.layout.web)` and initialize your `WebView`.
**5.** After clicking on `Google Button` create new `Intent` and start new `Activity`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, WebBrowser.class);
startActivity(i);
```

your `web.xml` can looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** For support of full screen you can use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```